# Why does shift-drag resizing a DateListPlot cause the line to disappear?

Tags: plotting, date-and-time, user-interface

Start with the following plot:

```
DateListPlot[FinancialData["IBM", "Jan. 1, 2004"]]
```

I want to resize it to make it a bit wider, so I use SHIFT + Mouse1 on the right-bottom corner handle to drag it out a bit:

[image: time series]

But the line has now vanished and the plot is a mess! What happened?
This happens in all *Mathematica* versions I believe so am I doing something wrong? Shift-dragging to resize works on other plots like `Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}]` for instance.

This GIF shows what happens the moment I press SHIFT and try to stretch the plot:
[image: gif showing datelistplot stretching]

Comment: Seems to work if you don't use `Shift`

Comment: @BobHanlon yes but then it will scale proportionally in the same aspect ratio. If I want to adjust the aspect ratio and stretch the plot then I have to use it, otherwise I'd have to adjust by using `AspectRatio` programmatically.

Comment: Instead of just clicking on the chart, double-click before resizing with `Shift`

Comment: @BobHanlon That doesn't work either - the box becomes gray instead of orange, as expected - but shift-dragging the right corner handle causes exactly the same problem in the image with long ticks and a missing line.

Comment: Must be version/OS dependent, works after double-clicking with `12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)`

Comment: @BobHanlon yes possibly - mine is 12.2.0 on Windows  10. I will report it.

Comment: same issue in version 11.3.0 (windows 10).  (`ListPlot[MapAt[AbsoluteTime, FinancialData["IBM", "Jan. 1, 2004"], {All, 1}]]` works as expected.)